# Произвольное появление букв

Tags: javascript, css

Есть задача. Появления текста в блоке, в произвольной последовательности, по буквам (Например для слова **Hello**, чтоб буквы появлялись в подобной последовательности **eHlol**). Тестовый блок

```
<div class="random-fading">
    Hello,<br>
    Javascript <b>is</b> an <a href="#">awesome</a> lan<i>g</i>uage
</div>
```

Единственное что пришло в голову, это обернуть каждую букву текста в `<span>` и потом показывать его с рандомный таймаутом. Но сложность обстоит с тэгами. Что с ними можно сделать? Убирать, оборачивать потом снова добавлять? Может быть это реализуется без JS с помощью СSS?

Comment: Не вполне понятно: в примере кода только слово "Hello" должно перемешаться, или все слова? Перемешивать ли буквы всего предложения, или только в рамках отдельных слов? Появляться это должно сразу, или постепенно?

Comment: все буквы, во всех словах, старт одновременный для всех букв вне зависимости от длины текста. Допустим чтоб весь текст отобразился за 1 секунду. Какие-то буквы появятся через 100мс, а какие-то через 900мс. Отображение текста не последовательное

Comment: Наверное, вариант – оборачивать каждую букву в `span`, делать ему прозрачность, и потом пошагово менять прозрачность.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Пока другого не придумал. [Каждую букву обернуть в `span`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5062698/556876) с классом, который ставит `visibility: hidden`, одновременно запихнув все созданные `span`'ы в массив. Массив случайно перемешать. И затем по очереди у каждого из массива снимать прячущий класс:

```js
var spans = []
  ,allTextNodes = getTextNodes( document.getElementById('b-test'))
  ,i
  ,timer
;

/**
 * recursively get all text nodes as an array for a given element
 */
function getTextNodes(node) {
  var childTextNodes = [];
  if (!node.hasChildNodes()) return;
  var childNodes = node.childNodes;
  for (var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (childNodes[i].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      childTextNodes.push(childNodes[i]);
    } else if (childNodes[i].nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      Array.prototype.push.apply(childTextNodes, getTextNodes(childNodes[i]));
    }
  }

  return childTextNodes;
}

/**
 * given a text node, wrap each character in the
 * given tag.
 */
function wrapEachCharacter(textNode, tag, className = '') {
  var text = textNode.nodeValue;
  var parent = textNode.parentNode;

  var characters = text.split('');
  var elements = [];
  characters.forEach(function(character) {
    var element = document.createElement(tag);
    element.className = className;
    var characterNode = document.createTextNode(character);
    element.appendChild(characterNode);
    parent.insertBefore(element, textNode);
    spans.push(element);
  });

  parent.removeChild(textNode);
}

allTextNodes.forEach(function(textNode) {
  wrapEachCharacter(textNode, 'span', 'h');
});

/**
 * Shuffles array in place.
 * @param {Array} a items The array containing the items.
 */
function shuffle(a) {
  var j, x, i;
  for (i = a.length; i; i--) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    x = a[i - 1];
    a[i - 1] = a[j];
    a[j] = x;
  }
}

shuffle(spans);
i = spans.length - 1;

function showOne() {
  spans[i--].className = "";
  if (i < 0) clearInterval(timer);
}
timer = window.setInterval(showOne.bind(this), 100);
```

```css
span.h{visibility: hidden}
```

```html
<div class="random-fading" id="b-test">
  Hello,
  <br>Javascript <b>is</b> an 
  <a href="#">awesome</a> lan<i>g</i>uage
</div>
```

Что улучшить: пробелы не надо оборачивать и прятать – только видимые буквы, иначе нарушается видимый «ритм» появления символов.

Ещё недостаток: слова перестают быть целыми словами и могут рваться переносом строки. Выход: оборачивать каждое слово в `<nobr>`.

Comment: Правильное оборачивание тоже оказалось проблемой. Если бить на слова по whitespace, то пробелы возникают внутри тегов. `<a<nobr>href="#">`. Если разбивать уже отфильтрованный от тегов текст, тогда возможен вариант вроде `<nobr>......<br></nobr>`

Comment: бить нужно внутри только-текстовых нод.

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо! Пока ждал ответа, сам набросал, но ваш вариант мне нравится больше)
В процессе столкнулся еще с одним моментом. Слова больше не являются словами и переносы строк могут сыграть злую шутку. Думаю правильно будет оборачивать слова перед обработкой в отдельные контейнеры которые будут виртуальными словами.

```js
$(function() {
 $('.random-fading').each(function() {
  var input = $(this).html();
  var charRegexp = /<[^>]*>/g;
  var wordRegexp = /\S+/g;
  var match;
  var offset = 1;
  var replacer = [];
  var wordReplacer = [];
  var output = '<nobr>';

  while ((match = charRegexp.exec(input)) != null) {
   replacer[match.index - offset] = match[0];
   offset += match[0].length;
  }

  input = input.replace(charRegexp, '');
  offset = 1;

  while ((match = wordRegexp.exec(input)) != null) {
   wordReplacer[match.index - offset] = true;
   offset += 14;
   //console.log(match[0]);
  }

  input.split('').forEach(function(value, key) {
   if (/^\S$/.exec(value)) {
    output += '<span class="h">' + value + '</span>';
   } else {
    //пустые символы не оборачиваем
    output += value;
   }

   if (wordReplacer[key] && key != 0) {
    output += '</nobr><nobr>';
   }

   if (replacer[key]) {
    //добавить тег
    output += replacer[key];
   }
  });

  //console.log(output);

  output += '</nobr>';
  $(this).html(output);
 });

 $('.random-fading span.h').each(function() {
  var self = $(this);

  setTimeout(function() {
   self.removeClass('h');
  }, Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 100));
 });
});
```

```css
.random-fading span.h {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s linear all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="random-fading">
 Hello,<br>Javascript


 <b>is</b> an <a href="#">awesome</a> lan<i>g</i>uage
</div>
<div class="random-fading">
 ОченьДлинныйТекст КоторыйДолженПереноситсяПоСловам, ПростаяПроверкаНаВсякийСлучайАТоМалоЛиЧтоТоПойдётНеТак:-(((((
</div>
```

Comment: верно подмечен момент со словами и переносами!